# load document object for different page

Tags: javascript, dom

A preface: I'm new to javascript and trying to create a web visualization using html5 canvas.

Using the document object I can traverse the DOM of the page that my script is embedded in, but if I want to access the DOM of another page how would I go about that?

I searched around quite a bit but couldn't find anything. Being new to javascript I am somewhat unsure of what to search/where to begin, which is why I posted here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to load another page in a fashion that would allow you to access its DOM would be to use an iframe. This would, however, be subject to the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

If you want a cross domain solution, you would probably be better off using a server side process to request the document, parsing it there, and then presenting the data you care about as [JSON](http://json.org/) to the client.

Comment: It needs to be cross domain. Could you suggest a direction to start implementing a solution? I've been looking at XMLHttpRequest but that appears to also be subject to the same origin policy. I'm at somewhat of a loss as to where to even begin. Thanks for the help!